# Frazil: Could this similarly be used to describe the ice which forms in liquids too close to the back of the fridge?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

**Frazil**:

Soft or amorphous ice formed by the accumulation of ice crystals in water that is too turbulent to freeze solid.

.

Could frazil similarly be used to describe the ice which forms in liquids too close to the back of the fridge?

In these scenarios, it is seemingly the opposite: the turbulent blown cool air is cold enough to form a few ice crystals in say, your milk or grape juice, but the latent heat in the unshifting environment (just above freezing) rather than the shifting waters keeps ice from fully freezing liquids.

Comment: "Liquids too close to the back of the fridge" are not turbulent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Frazil ice is a term more specific to open water however most people would perhaps normally call a frozen food liquid

**[Slush](http://www2.gi.alaska.edu/~eicken/he_teach/GEOS615icenom/form/types.html#Slush)**
defined here as **Thick accumulations** of frazil ice, usually indicative of rough surface conditions which **induce turbulent mixing** in the upper water column.

Just conjecture as I don't free-stand looking at it but my fridge, new as it is, chatters a lot in use and it may be such vibrations that contribute to movement during cooling.

Comment: That much the OP has already gathered and stated in the question.

Comment: Btw, Frazil is also called *slush* as well as "lolly ice."